Create Controller Inside a folder in CodeIgniter 4
how do i create a controller inside a folder programmatically using the Spark make command ?
i wrote this code:
    $controllerName = service('request')->getpost('controllerName');
    $controllerPath = service('request')->getpost('controllerPath');
    $controllerFullPath = APPPATH.'Views/'.$controllerPath;
    if (!is_dir($viewFullPath)) {
      mkdir($viewFullPath, 0777, true);
    }

$output = shell_exec('php spark make:controller '.$viewPath.'/'.$viewName);
    print_r($output);die;

the output :
the folder will be created but no controller file.

It is easy to use the built-in commands .
Before that, set the write permissions for the app/Controllers directory
command('make:controller API/Post')


To create a controller inside a folder using the spark make:controller command in CodeIgniter 4, you need to structure the command correctly. Here's how you can do it:
Correct Command Syntax
Use a backslash () to specify the folder and controller name. For example:
php spark make:controller Folder/ControllerName

If you want to create a controller named UserController inside a folder Admin:
php spark make:controller Admin/UserController


We can create with three different ways:

Programmatically Generate:
Use PHP code to dynamically create a file in app/Controllers,
writing the necessary PHP controller code as a string to the file.

Manually Creating the File:
Create a PHP file in the app/Controllers directory and write the
controller class manually, extending CodeIgniter\Controller.

Using Spark CLI:
Run php spark make:controller Name in the terminal to generate a
controller named Name in the app/Controllers directory.


